# Could not load mat file generated from Visual SFM with scipy loadmat

Tags: scipy

I was trying to read mat file generated from Visual SFM through scipy loadmat function as follows:

```
import scipy.io as scio
data = scio.loadmat("IMG_5589.mat")
```

However, an error occurred as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/wangxinqi/Python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio.py", line 207, in loadmat
MR, file_opened = mat_reader_factory(file_name, appendmat, **kwargs)
File "/home/wangxinqi/Python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio.py", line 63, in mat_reader_factory
mjv, mnv = get_matfile_version(byte_stream)
File "/home/wangxinqi/Python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/io/matlab/miobase.py", line 241, in get_matfile_version
raise ValueError('Unknown mat file type, version %s, %s' % ret)
ValueError: Unknown mat file type, version 20, 0
```

The mat file is from Visual SFM. In the Visual SFM pipeline, pictures captured from different perspectives with a camera will be gathered for 3D reconstruction. Each image will produce a mat file and a sift file in the Visual SFM processing. I have been stuck in loading data in the mat file.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you point to documentation for this file format?  Just because it has a `.mat` tag does not mean it is the MATLAB format that `loadmat` can read.

Comment: Well, it is my fault. You can get the mat file from the link:                                  https://github.com/cvlab-epfl/tf-lift                                                                                             You can get a mat file in example folder, my question is from the mat file there.

Comment: I can't load that .mat with `octave` either.